# Spree Commerce show only certain product to a specif user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, spree

Spree Commerce 3.6.
I have created some variants of the same product with different price. I want to show for a specific user only certain variant of product. Is possible?

Example: product A, variants: a1, a2, a3. For the user foo@example.com is possible to show only a2?

Comment: Please **show us some code**. It's very unclear how to answer your question without seeing more context. `if user.email == "foo@example.com"; ...; else ....` ??!!

Comment: Is possible to do this without programming? My question is about a feature of spree not about programming a new feature.

Comment: *Without programming*? How would you expect that to work? Again, I have no idea how to answer your question without seeing some more context. (And besides, can't we just achieve this by a single `if` statement?)

Comment: Is there a front end built-in mode to achieve this? If not I am going to programming my feature.

Comment: How do you expect to add a "front end mode" with no code? I still don't understand your question.

Comment: I repeat: spree offers this feature out of the box or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177553/discussion-between-tom-lord-and-user1066183).